# insert div with jquery into another jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a form with the help of jQuery html

```
var formsz =    $(this).closest('div').parent().parent().parent();
($(formsz).html());
```

but the problem is that I want to add another div into this `($(formsz).html())`. But I haven't  found any solution for this. Please tell me how I can insert this div.

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
    <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" step="1" min="1" max="89">
    <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
    </div>
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: use append to add an element to an existing one formsz.append(yourElement) or prepand if you want to add the new element as first child formsz.prepand(yourElement)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(formsz).append('<div class="quantity buttons_added">'
        +'<input type="button" class="minus" value="-">'
        +'<input type="number" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" step="1" min="1" max="89">'
        +'<input type="button" class="plus" value="+">'
        +'</div>');
```

Comment: i am using your method but it is giving me Object object error

Comment: it is not adding into this form.

Comment: I can't really help you unless you post code. Dump your code into a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'append' function of jquery to add an element to an existing one `formsz.append(yourElement)` or 'prepend' if you want to add the new element as first child `formsz.prepend(yourElement)`